# Retrieving large datasets from redis

Tags: ubuntu, networking, redis

An app on one server queries redis which runs on another server. The result data set is about 250k from a query `zrangebyscore objects:locations -inf +inf` which seems to take 40 seconds on the app server.

When the command is performed using `redis-cli` on the redis server or the app server, in both cases they also take around 40 seconds to complete as reported by `redis-cli`.

The redis server uses about 15% of CPU during the query.

**Question:** Is taking 40 seconds to retrieving 250k records considered slow? Is it possible to speed it up to take seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it depends on the average size of the items.

On my system, retrieving 250K items of 10 bytes with a zrangebyscore takes only 113 ms.
With 100 bytes items, it takes 228 ms. With 1 Kb items, it takes 4033 ms.

So except if your items are much bigger than this, I would say your 40 seconds response time is pretty bad.

Redis is not designed to work well with virtual memory. If Redis memory is swapped out, performance is generally catastrophic, so I would say your first action should be to avoid Redis memory to be swapped out.

I would try to dump the Redis database (with bgsave, to be sure that all pages are back in RAM), and then try the zrangebyscore again (and several time) to see if the response time is better.

Update:

Here is the command I use to build the content:

```
$ python -c 'for x in range(0,250000): print "ZADD objects:locations 0.1 %0115d" % (x)' | redis-cli | wc
```

Here is the command I use to time the query:

```
$ time redis-cli -h <hostname> zrangebyscore objects:locations -inf +inf >/dev/null
```

Comment: After `bgsave` it now takes about 25 secs for 250k. Each item looks like `"94:47mr7jYTroxQMwdKoPQuJoc9Vs9S9qCUAL6Ek4qyNFWJdqgBZRn4RYY2QjQfqEMJZVWPscupSgaqmUn1dpdUTC4fQsu3yjN:1405009897099"`, how many bytes is this?

Comment: Will running the query using `redis-cli` be a good way to judge the speed? Not sure if having to display the entire result set on screen will slow it down significantly...

Comment: I spin up a new server and only have redis running so no virtual memory is used. The same query also takes 25 secs for 250k items.

Comment: So around 115 bytes per item ... if you are on a physical machine with a sensible CPU (i.e. not antediluvian) with a 1 GbE network, it should be faster. Perhaps you could try to run redis-cli locally (on the same machine as the Redis server) to see if Redis is CPU bound or network bound.

Comment: I do all my measurements by redirecting the output of redis-cli to /dev/null (or in a file) to avoid the painful display. Otherwise the performance of the terminal may be a limiting factor.

Comment: After following your suggestion to redirect the output of redis-cli to a file, the operation now takes only 400ms on both the app server and the redis server itself! The command used it `time cat redisCmd | redis-cli -h redis.mywebsite.com > result.txt`, does `time` accurately measures the query time accurately? `result.txt` turns out to be 14MB

Comment: For this kind of query (i.e. quite heavy), yes timing redis-cli is quite accurate.

Comment: I checked results.txt on the redis server, the last line states it took 0.5 sec, which is pretty close to what `time` reported. The results.txt on the app server does not state the time taken, so i will assume its 400ms as `time` reported.

Comment: This means if the app takes 30 seconds to complete the function that includes querying redis with this command, then the slowdown is with something in the function itself and not waiting for redis to transfer the result set over to the app