# Redis Node - Querying a list of 250k items of ~15 bytes takes at least 10 seconds

Tags: node.js, redis

I'd like to query a whole list of 250k items of ~15 bytes each.

Each item (some coordinates) is a 15 bytes string like that `xxxxxx_xxxxxx_xxxxxx`.

I'm storing them using this function :

```
function setLocation({id, lat, lng}) {
    const str = `${id}_${lat}_${lng}`

    client.lpush('locations', str, (err, status) => {
        console.log('pushed:', status)
    })
}
```

Using nodejs, doing a `lrange('locations', 0, -1)` takes between 10 seconds and 15 seconds.

Slowlog redis lab:
[image]

I tried to use sets, same results.

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24681708/9726037)

This shouldn't take more than a few milliseconds.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Update:
I'm using an instance on Redis lab

Comment: also include the code for query. >"I'm using an instance on Redis lab" also consider query round trip time.

Comment: Is it possible that you have run out of memory? What does the `INFO MEMORY` command show you? I'm specifically interested in the mem fragmentation ratio.